# Solving "TclError: Layout TLabelFrame not found"

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So I am trying to apply a simple style to a labelframe widget with the following code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Just checking your Python version to import Tkinter properly.
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk as ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.ttk import ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
bls = ttk.Style()
bls.configure('Black.TLabelFrame', background="#222222")

dayframe = ttk.Labelframe(root, style='Black.TLabelFrame', height=200, width=150, relief=tk.SUNKEN, 
    text="Hello")
dayframe.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
root.mainloop()
```

But when I run this code I get the error message:

> TclError: Layout Black.TLabelFrame not found

I don't understand what I am doing wrong...

Comment: use `Black.TLabelframe` with lower `f`

Comment: I encountered this issue too. The documentation by [nmt](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) wrote `TLabelFrame`. Recommend the typo there be correct too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Black.TLabelframe` with lower `f`

Comment: Works like a charme, thank you